# How to install paramiko 2.12.0 with pip 20.3.4 and python 3.5 on windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pip

I need to use those legacy versions on windows 11, what I currently have:

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.3.4
setuptools 18.2
```

And `python 3.5.0`.

I ran into all kinds of issues including:

- 1:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 3.5 reached the end of its life on September 13th, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.5 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 3.5 in January 2021. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
```

when I tried `python -m pip install paramiko==2.12.0`, then installation process stopped. This error also happens when I do `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-deps setuptools`, and process stopped.

- 2:

```
Python\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'project_urls'
  warnings.warn(msg)
error in paramiko setup command: 'extras_require' must be a dictionary whose values are strings or lists of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers.
```

when I tried to install paramiko 2.12.0 from setup.py file

- 3:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 3.5 reached the end of its life on September 13th, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.5 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 3.5 in January 2021. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pip-20.3.4-py3.5.egg (20.3.4)
```

when I tried to upgrade `setuptools`.

How can I install `paramiko 2.12.0` successfully on this Windows 11?